# how to draw a graph by using html and css?

Tags: html, css

I got a project where i need to insert a bar graph into the website. I cant use the image of the graph. Is there any other method to draw this? Some way i can draw it in middle and give explanation about the graph below it.

Comment: Try canvas on fly scripting (HTML5)

Comment: Are you allowed to use JavaScript and/or third party libraries to aid the creation of your graph?

Answer (score 3):

If you do not want to use an HTML 5 canvas, you might try using DIV elements with different color backgrounds.

```html
<div style="height: 150px; width:100px; background:black;">
  <div style="height: 10px; margin-top:17px; width:10px; background:red;" /><br/>
  <div style="height: 10px; margin-top:17px; width:30px; background:green;" /><br/>
  <div style="height: 10px; margin-top:17px; width:70px; background:yellow;" /><br/>
  <div style="height: 10px; margin-top:17px; width:96px; background:blue;" /><br/>
</div>
```

**It's crude, but can be effective for a quick hack.**

You can set all of the static values in the chart using CSS, and then use the Style tag to change the length of the bars.

Answer (score 1):

There are many javascript libraries for drawing charts. You could try [chartjs](http://www.chartjs.org/) for example, or read this article that provides a list of [50 libraries for charts and graphs](http://techslides.com/50-javascript-charting-and-graphics-libraries/).